# If $0 \lt x \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$, is $\cos(x) \le \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \le \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How can I find the following product using elementary trigonometry?

> Suppose $0 \lt x \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$
>   is an angle measured in radians. Use the trigonometric circle and
>   show that $\cos(x) \le \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \le \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$.

I have been trying to solve this question. I can't figure out whether or not the solution requires a trigonometric circle or if it can be done using another method.

Comment: note that $\cos x \leq 1$ and take a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Comment: But we have for $$\theta=\pi$$ , $$\cos(\pi)=-1$$

Comment: It's  $$ /pi/2 $$there was a mistake in writing

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Answer (score 3):

Draw a segment $OAB$ of the unit circle such that $x=\angle AOB$ is an acute angle.  Let $C$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $B$ to $OA$.  Let $D$ be the point on $OB$ extended such that $AD$ is perpendicular to $OA$.

Now calculate and compare the three areas of the triangle $OBC$, the circular segment $OAB$ and the triangle $OAD$, then do a little algebra.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints.** (without using circles)

For the first inequality define $f(\theta) =\theta \cos(\theta) $ and $g(\theta) =\sin(\theta) $. Then $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(\theta) <g'(\theta) $ for $\theta\in (0,\pi/2)$. What can you conclude?

For the second inequality it is well known that 
$$\sin(\theta) <\theta$$
and it is easily proven with the use of Mean Value Theorem. After that use the fact that $\cos\theta <1$.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please keep in mind that this answer came from another question which is now merged with this. They didn't say to use the trig circle there. Please take that into consideration before downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

since x, sinx and cosx are all positive in (0, pi/2), we can write the ineq as
cosxsinx <= x
or 2cosxsinx <= 2x
or sin2x <= 2x
or siny <= y where y= 2x lies in (0, pi).
however, siny <= y is extremely easy to prove (can also be seen from graph).